# FullCalendar not showing allDay events correctly

Tags: fullcalendar

Why an event like this will stop on the 9th and not show in the 10th on the calendar? To me this event is inclusive of the 10th. I believe it work find in the 1v of the calendar and changed when I upgraded to 2v.

```
{
    allDay: true,
    title: 'Long Event',
    start: '2014-09-07',
    end: '2014-09-10'
},
```

Answer (score 2):

Both v1 and v2 treat the endParam as denoting the end of the last day being exclusive.

According to the [documentation of v2](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/endParam/) it is stated that

> **endParam**
>
> A parameter of this name will be sent to each JSON event feed. It describes **the exclusive end of the interval** being fetched.

If you take a look at the [documentation for v1](http://fullcalendar.io/docs1/event_data/endParam/):

> **endParam**
>
> The value of this GET parameter will be a UNIX timestamp denoting the end of the last visible day (**exclusive**).